# Python: return type hint of arbitrary depth dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, mypy

I am using a defaultdict collection to easily build an arbitrary depth python dictionary as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime


def recursive_dict() -> defaultdict:
    """enable arbitrary depth dictionary declaration"""
    return defaultdict(recursive_dict)


dbdict = recursive_dict()

dbdict["entity"]["surface"] = "this is a string"
dbdict["entity"]["spotlight"]["uri"] = "http://test.com/test"
dbdict["entity"]["spotlight"]["curation"]["date"] = datetime.now()
```

which works fine as expected but mypy type checking fails with the following error message:

```
error: Missing type parameters for generic type "defaultdict"  [type-arg]
```

I am confused as how to fix this since I'd like to use the recursive_dict function for any type of dictionary that I'll build.

Comment: I cant reproduce this. $mypy test.py :Success: no issues found in 1 source file

Comment: Maybe because of different mypy options? I have disallow_any_generics = True
check_untyped_defs = True
no_implicit_reexport = True
disallow_untyped_defs = True

Comment: thats true with   $mypy --strict test.py   it is indeed reproducable. Maybe you can add that to the question

Comment: `defaultdict[str, Any]` (parameters have the same meaning as in regular `dict` - key type (invariant) and value type (covariant)) is not a fully safe hint, and it doesn't protect you from bugs. For example, `dbdict['foo'] = 'bar'; dbdict['foo']['bar'] = 'baz'` is an easy to make mistake (forgotten key of level 2 in first assignment), which won't trigger `mypy` error. Consider using `TypedDict` or dataclasses instead/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Defauldict` is expecting a typing of its parameters.

In this case the typing wont be so trivial since its an returning a `defaultdict` once and after that a nested `defaultdict`.

A way how you could satisfy mypy would providing the type `str` and `Any`  to the `defaultdict`.

```
from typing import Any
    
def recursive_dict() -> defaultdict[str , Any]: 
    """enable arbitrary depth dictionary declaration"""
    return defaultdict(recursive_dict)
```

Comment: The `Any` here actually silences the type checker. Moreover, it is indeed intended and necessary, because the construct in the question is not type-safe.